# Laravel: get all data from View object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Just wondering if there is an equivalent method or workaround to

```
Session:all()
```

for the View object?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  `Session:all()` gets all the session data, you want to get what? All the data from a view?  I don't quite understand.

Comment: Laravel documentation says you can pass data to a view as second parameter to make() method or using with() etc etc. So you can pass data to a view using the View Object, can you access that same data using the View object. Or is hidden only available internally for rendering?

Comment: So you want to know, within a view, what variables have been passed to it from the controller?

Comment: No. Specifically I want to know from within a View Composer what data is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `getData()` is what you're looking for.

From the Laravel Documentation: http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.View.View.html

Comment: So simple. arghh. Thanks a lot.
Also cheers for the link. Sure beats scrolling through source code for method signatures.

Comment: how ca it be accessed?